# Canadian TR Visa conditions

Tags: visas, canada

I am currently in Israel and my visa to go Canada is being processed. I need to go to my home  country to visit my family before leaving for Canada.

Is it possible for me to go to Sri Lanka which is my home country and leave for Canada from there or do i have to fly directly from Israel where my application submitted?

Comment: TR visa? Temporary resident? And what citizenship do you have?

Comment: @MarkMayo Canada calls its visitor visa as a "temporary resident" visa.

Comment: @MarkMayo: I was thinking "TR" was an abbreviation for "transit" and was just about to ask for more details.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**.  Your Canadian visa allows you to enter Canada, it does not specify the route you have to fly to get there.

Naturally you have to make sure you are allowed to transit through any other countries on the way, but if you have a valid Canadian visa, transiting through the EU or the UK should not be a problem.